# Организация git репозитория с веткой разработки и веткой релиза

Tags: git, github, git-branch, github-pages

Делаю проект на `github` с возможностью выкладывать время от времени сборки на `Github Pages`.

Подскажите как правильно будет организовать ветки в самом репозитории.

Одна ветка `master` будет для разработки, другая `gh-pages` для сборок на `Github Pages`.

Структура проекта в ветке `master`:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── app.0fb09369.css
│   ├── app.5cec07dd.css
│   ├── app.5cec07dd.js
│   ├── app.5cec07dd.map
│   ├── app.eda8459b.js
│   ├── app.eda8459b.map
│   └── index.html
├── node_modules
│   ├── ...
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── ...
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   ├── sounds
│   ├── ...
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── index.html
├── LICENSE
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
├── typings.json
└── yarn.lock
```

Можно ли как нибудь сделать так чтобы ветка `gh-pages` не содержала лишних файлов. Например так:

```
.
├── assets
│   ├── images
│   ├── sounds
│   ├── ...
├── .gitignore
├── app.5cec07dd.js
├── app.5cec07dd.css
├── app.5cec07dd.map
└── index.html
```

Насколько сложно будет это сделать и можно ли будет это как-то автоматизировать?

Как при этом избежать проблем со слиянием веток? Создание релизных версий ведь будет происходить через несколько коммитов и могут накопиться конфликты например в том же `index.html` или в папке `assets`. При этом по сути файлы нужно просто заменить без слияния. Если ли в `git` способ слияния похожий на простую замену файлов без возни с конфликтами?

Буду благодарен даже просто за ссылки на команды, которые могут помочь в этом.

Comment: Ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579546/git-excludesfile-for-a-branch/29583813#29583813

Comment: `--orhaned` — это правильный шаг. Другое дело, как организовать работу, чтобы минимизировать количество конфликтов. Скорее в вашем случае много ручной работы придётся делать.

Comment: Ну а вообще посмотрите на стратегии `merge`, а именно на `ours`, `theirs`.

Comment: https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-gh-pages

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас вижу такое решение:

1. Копирую файлы необходимые для релиза из `master` во временную папку.
2. Перехожу в `gh-pages` и заменяю файлы в этой веткой файлами из временной папки.

Как раз [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969050/how-to-create-a-new-empty-branch-for-a-new-project) информацию как сделать ветку без ответвления.

Вот скрипт для переноса релизной версии в другую ветку:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var tmp = require('tmp');

var tmpDir = tmp.dirSync();

var lastMasterCommitMessage = shell.exec('git log -1 --pretty=%B').stdout.trim();

shell.exec('yarn run build');
shell.cp('dist/*', tmpDir.name);
shell.exec('git checkout gh-pages');
shell.rm('-f', '*.html', '*.js', '*.map');
shell.cp(tmpDir.name + '/*', './');
shell.exec('git add .');
shell.exec('git commit -m "last master commit message: ' + lastMasterCommitMessage + '"');
shell.exec('git checkout master');
```

Зависимости: `yarn add -D shelljs tmp`.